# How to run a function inside a function if a condition is met

Tags: php, mysql

Please I've been trying to create a function that would query a DB, select from the table, and if the row count is not equal to 6, then a row from the table and repeat (or maybe duplicate) until the row count is equal to 6. I've search for this here in StackOverflow, but didn't get anything close. Please if you have a similar link to this, please post it here, and I'll give it a go. 
Here's my code:

```
//List All active adverts
function showActiveAdverts()
{

    $status = 1;
    //Build final queries.
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
             status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6") or die(mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

# My question here, check if the $count >= 1 && $count != 6, then do getDefaultBannner() and repeat it until it runs for 6 times.
    if($count >= 1){ 
        do{ 
            $list[] = $row['id']; 
        }while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
        return $list;
    }
    else{ return FALSE; }
    }
```

Here's the code for getDefaultBannner()

```
function getDefaultBannner()
{
    $status = 6;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."' ") 
            or die(mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);


    if($count >= 1){ 
        do{ 
            $list[] = $row['id']; 
        }while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
        return $list;
    }
    else{ return FALSE; }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to try do that on sql level instead by means of a `UNION`, so that you _always_ get back 6 rows, no matter what. That would simplify your logic and keep things more robust.

Comment: Here's what I am trying to achieve. I have 6 advert slots, that should be filled with the default image, if no active advert was found. If I query the DB, and I get less than 6 active adverts (based on their status), the other empty slots should be filled with the default image. Will `UNION` solve this on an sql level? @arkascha

Comment: Well, using `UNION ALL` you can combine the results of two `SELECT` queries into one. THe first query would be the randomized one, the second one picking that default banner 6 times. That means you always get back _at least_ 6 rows which you can now `LIMIT` to 6 in total. This would allow to run only a single statement, though that one is slightly more complex. The tricky bit is the "6 times". That requires either a stored procedure, or, easy and pragmatic, simply store the default banner 6 times in your table.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha, your explanation is helpful! I would have loved to use the "easy and pragmatic" procedure to get the banner displayed, but the challenge is that these banners have an id, and storing the banner 6 different times in the DB will cause it to have 6 different ids, which is not something I really want to do. Is there a way you can explain how I can get the "tricky bit" so as to make the default banner have just one id throughout the advert slots?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code as this

```
//List All active adverts

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
             status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6") or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count >= 1 && $count != 6)
  $list = getDefaultBannner();
else
  $list = showActiveAdverts($query);

function showActiveAdverts($query)
{

    $status = 1;
    //Build final queries.

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    if($count >= 1){ 
        do{ 
            $list[] = $row['id']; 
        }while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
        return $list;
    }
    else{ return FALSE; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Gunasegar, but how do I call the first query?